# NDSolve error in Functional Delay Diff Eq

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to use Mathematica to study an equation that has an unusual dependence on past states, i.e. some kind of a Delay Diff Eq. For the sake of this post, we can say that the equation I would like to simulate is $$x'(t)=\max_{s\in[t-T,t]}x(s)$$ where $T$ is the size of the delay. I would also provide some initial history function $x(t)=\phi (t)$ for $x\in [-T,0]$. Again, for the sake of keeping this post simple, my initial history function will just be $\phi(t)=1$.
My (somewhat naive) attempt at implementing this equation using NDSolve was:

```
NDSolve[x'[t] == MaxValue[{x[s], t - 1 <= s && s <= t}, s] && x[t /; t < 0] == 1, x, {t, 0, 1}]
```

which throws a series of errors of the form

```
StringForm: Item 2 requested in "delayed time `1` = `2` computed at `3`=`4` did not evaluate to a real number." out of range; 1 items available.
```

I can't parse what the error is telling me, so I am not sure how to modify my code into something that might work. Does anybody have any suggestions about how I might correct my code to make it something that NDSolve can handle? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not to use simple numerical algorithm, like predictor-corrector?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have considered writing my own simple numerical algorithm, but my reasoning was that if possible, I would like to take advantage of the more sophisticated methods available to NDSolve. I know NDSolve can handle delay differential equations, so I was hoping it could handle this delay-like functional diff eq. Do you have an idea of how this can be made to work?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not DDE, this is functional equation. It looks like we can't solve this functional equation with `NDSolve` in the current version.